# Jquery - Creating a general language file to declare defaults for any plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery, internationalization

Like most people, I use a bunch of jquery plugins on my website. From Twitter bootstrap to jquery ui datepicker and so on.

But I need my website to be multilingual, so **I created a general language file called english.js , and in that file I want to declare some of the defaults from plugins as well as other language variables**.

The problem is that all these plugins have varying structures to declare defaults. I saw a couple of questions already ( [jquery - setting plugin defaults?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357607/jquery-setting-plugin-defaults), [Globally defining jQuery plugin parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6735890/globally-defining-jquery-plugin-parameters) , [jQuery plugin defaults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6881212/jquery-plugin-defaults) , ...). But they are not clear.

**STRUCTURE 1**

```
$.fn.ajaxStatus = function (params)
{
    var settings = $.extend(
            {
                defaultLoadingText :"Loading...",
                defaultSavingText  :"Saving...",
                defaultDoneText    :"Done",
                defaultRedirectText:"Redirecting...",
                defaultErrorText   :"Oops! Our bad, something wrong.";
            },$.fn.ajaxStatus.defaults,
            params),
});
```

**STRUCTURE 2**

```
   jQuery.fn.extend({
        shrinker:function (options) {
            var opts = $.extend({
                "moreText":"Read more", 
                "lessText":"hide",
            }, $.fn.shrinker.defaults, options);
   });
```

**THE QUESTION**

Without modifying the plugin, is it possible to assign some defaults for the function that will be used every time I use the plugin?
How can I define the language defaults in an external file?

Right now, I have this in my language file, but it feels wrong, is this how you do it?

```
if ($.fn.ajaxStatus !== undefined) {
    $.fn.ajaxStatus.defaults =
    {
        defaultLoadingText :"Loading2...",
        defaultSavingText  :"Saving2...",
        defaultDoneText    :"Done2",
        defaultRedirectText:"Redirecting2...",
        defaultErrorText   :"Oops! Our bad, something wrong"
    };
}
```

Thanks in advance for you help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I could see doing it in one object, like this:

```
var en = {
    defaultLoadingText: "Loading...",
    defaultSavingText: "Saving...",
    defaultDoneText: "Done",
    defaultRedirectText: "Redirecting...",
    defaultErrorText: "Oops! Our bad, something wrong.";
    moreText: "Read more", 
    lessText: "hide"
};
```

Assuming there's no overlap in option names between plugins, you could just start your plugins with:

```
$('').ajaxStatus(en);
$('').shrinker(en);
```

Most plugins take in an options object and ignore the extra properties. If you have some other options you want to pass to a particular plugin, you just use `$.extend()`:

```
$('').ajaxStatus($.extend({}, { success: function () {} }, en));
```

If you really wanted to keep the plugin options separate, just create another level:

```
var en = {
    ajaxStatus: {
        defaultLoadingText: "Loading...",
        defaultSavingText: "Saving...",
        defaultDoneText: "Done",
        defaultRedirectText: "Redirecting...",
        defaultErrorText: "Oops! Our bad, something wrong.";
    },
    shrinker: {
        moreText: "Read more", 
        lessText: "hide"
    }
};
```

Then:

```
$('').ajaxStatus(en.ajaxStatus);
$('').shrinker(en.shrinker);
```

Finally, you could get fancy and make it easier to get different languages by storing them all in one multi-layered object:

```
var localizedOptions = {
    'en-US': {
        ajaxStatus: {
            defaultLoadingText: "Loading...",
            defaultSavingText: "Saving...",
            defaultDoneText: "Done",
            defaultRedirectText: "Redirecting...",
            defaultErrorText: "Oops! Our bad, something wrong.";
        },
        shrinker: {
            moreText: "Read more", 
            lessText: "hide"
        }
    },
    'es-ES': {
        ajaxStatus: {
            defaultLoadingText: "Cargar...",
            defaultSavingText: "Guardar...",
            defaultDoneText: "Terminado",
            defaultRedirectText: "Redirigir...",
            defaultErrorText: "¡Ay! Nuestra algo malo, malo.";
        },
        shrinker: {
            moreText: "Leer más", 
            lessText: "esconder"
        }
    } // ... etc.
};
```

And

```
$('').ajaxStatus(localizedOptions[navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage].ajaxStatus);
```

I must admit I haven't used something like this myself, because I usually get language files in the form of a resource file. In that case, I'll just output a single collection of key/value pairs via server-side logic and manually set the appropriate plugin properties.

In ASP.NET MVC:

```
<script>
var Resources = {};
@foreach (var kvp in ViewBag.Resources) {
Resources['@kvp.Key'] = "@kvp.Value";
}
</script>
```

This would output a different set, depending on the page I'm on.

Answer (score 3):

I have done somehow similar to this. But I am not giving the full implementation.

Here is how to do it.

Define your plugins params for language like this:

```
var options = {
    lang: "np" //your default language
};
```

Set up your language objects like this

```
var lang = {
    "en": {
        "var1" : "This is variable one"
    },
    "np": {
        "var1": "यो एउटा भेरियबल हो ।"  //Different text based on language initials
    }
};
```

Then you can simply create a function to read the value like this

```
function showVar1() {
    alert(lang[options.lang].var1);
}
```

[[Demo]](http://jsfiddle.net/5faBM/2/)<sub>*Its not a plugin based.*</sub>

Comment: you should really not use eval. especially for such a simple thing: `alert(lang[options.lang].var1);`

Comment: Eval is a bit risky. There must be a cleaner way of doing this. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: @lrsjng, I thought it would be more understandable. ha ha. I updated my answer.

Comment: @denislexic, Eval is risky when you don't trust the source. If the source is you, you don't need to think about the risk. But, I have updated the answer without the `eval`

Answer (score 1):

I think the way I'd do it is very similar to **STRUCTURE 1**. I think it's fine to override the plugins defaults like you're suggesting.

I'd build my plugin like this:

```
(function($){

    $.fn.pluginName = function (options) {
        /**
         * Here I'm extending an empty object to include the options
         * passed to the plugin, with the default options.
         */
        var opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.pluginName.defaults, options);

        // body of plugin here
    });

    // default values for plugin
    $.fn.pluginName.defaults = {
        defaultLoadingText :"Loading...",
        defaultSavingText  :"Saving...",
        defaultDoneText    :"Done",
        defaultRedirectText:"Redirecting...",
        defaultErrorText   :"Oops! Our bad, something wrong."
    };

})(jQuery);
```

Then in `english.js` you could redefine the `$.fn.plugin.defaults` object:

```
if ($.fn.pluginName) {
    // override the default values in the specified language
    $.fn.pluginName.defaults = {
        defaultLoadingText :"Loading...",
        defaultSavingText  :"Saving...",
        defaultDoneText    :"Done",
        defaultRedirectText:"Redirecting...",
        defaultErrorText   :"Oops! Our bad, something wrong."
    };
}
```

This would override the plugins default defaults. If that makes sense.